# Move assignment operator for a QWidget derivate?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, move-semantics

I have a QWidget derivate, let us assume the standard QWidget example

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow { //.. }
```

Does it make sense for this class MainWindow to fullfill the [Rule of Five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), I mean especially the Move constructor and move assignment ?

(Since the MainWindow should be created only once)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. QObject derived classes should never be copied and using the [Q_DISABLE_COPY](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_DISABLE_COPY) macro QObject and derived classes explicitly disable/hide the copy constructor and assignment operator by declaring them private. Possibly this has changed with recent releases and c++ 11 compatible compilers where they might now be declared deleted. [See here](http://woboq.com/blog/cpp11-in-qt5.html)

So the Rule of five is out. And looking at the Qt source I can't find any support for moving QObject derived classes ...

One final good read is [Qt Objects: Identity vs Value](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/object.html#identity-vs-value)